# TSQL get COUNT of rows that are missing from right table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There was one other SIMILAR answer but it is 2 pages long and my requirement doesn't need that. I have 2 tables, tableA and a tableB, and I need to find the COUNTS of rows that are present in tableA but are not present in tableB OR if update_on in tableB is not today's date.

My tables:

**tableA:**

```
release_id      book_name        release_begin_date  
----------------------------------------------------
1122           midsummer          2016-01-01          
1123           fool's errand      2016-06-01          
1124           midsummer          2016-04-01          
1125         fool's errand        2016-08-01
```

**tableB:**

```
release_id   book_name        updated_on
-----------------------------------------
1122         midsummer          2016-08-17 
1123         fool's errand      2016-08-16**
```

Expected result: Since each book is missing one release id, 1 is count. But in addition fool's errand's existing row in tableB has updated_on date of yesterday and not today, it needs to be counted in count_of_not_updated.

```
book_name       count_of_missing  count_of_not_updated
-------------------------------------------------------
midsummer          1                 0
fool's errand      1                 1
```

Note: Even though fool's errand is present in tableB, I need to show it in count_of_missing because it's updated_on date is yesterday and not today. I know it has to be a combination of a left join and something else, but the kicker here is not only getting the missing rows from left table but at the same time checking if the updated_on table was today's date and if not, count that row in count_of_not_updated.

Comment: I'm finding your final note a little confusing - it seems from your expected results that you have 1 missing for fool's errand (ID 1125) and 1 not updated (1123). But you are saying that you need 1123 to count as missing as well? So wouldn't that be 2 in the count_of_missing column for fool's errand?

Comment: @TPhe - fool's errand is missing one row and hence 1 in count_of_missing, but the existing row in tableB for fool's errand has an updated_on date that is not today(current day/getdate()), hence 1 in count_of_not_updated. Unlike midsummer, which has one missing row, and the row that is present, has an updated_on date of today (current day)

Comment: Ok, in that case I'm going to edit my query. The sentence in your question "Note: Even though fool's errand is present in tableB, I need to show it in count_of_missing because it's updated_on date is yesterday and not today" is still confusing to me.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(case when b.release_id is null then 1 else 0 end) as noReleaseID 
     , sum(case when datediff(d, b.release_date, getdate()) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as releaseDateNotToday
     , a.release_id
from tableA a 
left outer join tableB b on a.release_id = b.release_id
Group by a.release_id
```

This example uses a [sum function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) on a [case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to add up the instances where the case statement returns true. Note that the current code assumes, as in your example, that you are looking to count all old release dates from table b - more steps would be required if each book has multiple old release dates in table b, and you only want to compare to the most recent release date.

Comment: i'm not following your left join - it has column names instead of table name like so:  tableA left outer join tableB on tableA.release_id = tableB.release_id and tableA.book_name = tableB.book_name.

Comment: @DamonMatt My mistake, that is a copy/paste error. It should just be tableA left join to tableB. I've edited my post.

Comment: as you stated, there are lot more columns involved in actual query, but this gives me the framework to work off of. Thanks for your help - accepted your answer.

Comment: I forgot to ask you - how do I get the TOTAL number of release_id's in tableA? that would be total number of release_id's in tableA - right now if i do a count(a.release_id), that count matches the count of the noreleaseid, which is incorrect - the count(a.release_id) should be greater than the noreleaseid count.

Comment: Also, your datediff is checking for > 0, shouldn't that be = 0?

Comment: The way I've set up my query is to group by tableA.release_id - so you'll see the results for each release_id. In that context, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to have a count of the number of release_ids in tableA, since every group would have 1 in your example. So if you really want a count of all the ids, that makes me think that it might be better in a separate query; maybe a simple select count(release_id) from tableA.

Comment: The case and datediff functions there are trying to find to rows in which the release_date is not today. If the release_date is prior to today, it will result in a value of 1, which then gets added together by the sum function. If the release_date is today or in the future, it results in 0, which doesn't contribute to the total.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @tableA TABLE (release_id  INT, book_name  NVARCHAR(50), release_begin_date  DATETIME)
DECLARE @tableB TABLE (release_id  INT, book_name  NVARCHAR(50), updated_on  DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @tableA
VALUES
(1122,  'midsummer',          '2016-01-01'),          
(1123,  'fool''s errand',      '2016-06-01'),          
(1124,  'midsummer',          '2016-04-01'),          
(1125,  'fool''s errand',      '2016-08-01') 


INSERT INTO @tableB
VALUES
(1122, 'midsummer',      '2016-08-17'), 
(1123, 'fool''s errand',  '2016-08-16')

;WITH TmpTableA
AS
(
    SELECT
        book_name,
        COUNT(1) CountOfTableA
    FROM
        @tableA
    GROUP BY
        book_name
), TmpTableB
AS 
(
    SELECT
        book_name,
        COUNT(1) CountOfTableB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), updated_on, 112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 112) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) count_of_not_updated
    FROM
        @tableB
    GROUP BY
        book_name
)


SELECT
    A.book_name ,
    A.CountOfTableA - ISNULL(B.CountOfTableB, 0) AS count_of_missing,
    ISNULL(B.count_of_not_updated, 0) AS count_of_not_updated
FROM
    TmpTableA A LEFT JOIN 
    TmpTableB B ON A.book_name = B.book_name
```

Result:

```
book_name            count_of_missing count_of_not_updated
-------------------- ---------------- --------------------
fool's errand        1                1
midsummer            1                1
```